# Optimizer/minimizer for integer argument

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Does anybody know a python function (proven to work and having its description in internet) which able to make minimum search for a provided user function when argument is an array of integers?
Something like
scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b

scipy.optimize.leastsq

but for integers

Comment: Let me ask you a question, Do you know of an optimization algorithm proven to work over the range of integers? I'm not being clever, I really don't know the answer to that question. Most optimization algorithms work by approximating the derivative of the function you're trying to optimize, and I can see that being a problem if the function is only defined over integers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution for this problem. If you know the properties of the function it should be possible to deduce some bounds for the variables and then test all combinations. But that is not very efficient.

You could approximate a solution with scipy.optimize.leastsq and then round the results to integers. The quality of the result of course depends on the structure of the function.

Comment: could I approximate a solution with scipy.optimize.leastsq, I'd not ask this question. Unfortunately, scipy.optimize.leastsq and other like functions are not designed to work with integer arguments, they crash